# How can I make sure my custom filter script is executed the minimum number of times based on the size parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch to store documents (around 500 million) which have fairly complex rules to determine whether a given user can see them or not. In addition, each query will always have a maximum of, say, 2000 results applied using the "size" parameter. Ideally, for performance, we would be able to apply the data visibility algorithm in batches on the query results, but applying it on each document at filter time can also work.

In order to do this, we have tried writing a plugin which registers a custom filter script to apply this visibility restriction. Unfortunately, the performance hit has been unacceptable for our SLA (it added anywhere between 10 and 60 seconds to the query time, from around 250 milliseconds without the filter). Queries look something like this:

```
{
  "size" : 2000,
  "query" : {
    "user" : "John Biggs"
  },
  "filter" : {
    "script" {
      "script" : "entitlements",
      "lang" : "native",
      "params" : {
        "viewingUser" : "John Biggs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this situation, I'd ideally want the filter to be applied to the results of the query until 2000 results have been retrieved and then bail out. However, the filter still seems to be applied to every single query result. Is there a way to achieve this desired behaviour? Or is there a better way to apply a data visibility algorithm such as this? Note that the visibility for a given user can change intra-day and recomputation of ACLs would be very expensive.

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using the post filter. Do you also have facets/aggregations in your search requests?

Comment: Not currently, although we may need to support this later. I've also naively tried a filtered query by the way but this didn't improve things :-(

Comment: Forgot to mention I also tried with an AND filter without the query element and got similar results